# How to know if thread is blocked by Garbage Collection

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, .net-3.5, session-timeout

I have a client-server application with SQL server on the backend.

I am running some resource intensive task (takes around 30 hours to complete).  The user is given 3 minutes of Session.  Every 2 minutes I have a separate thread renewing the session.

However, once in a while the thread is paused because the garbage collector activates and blocks the threads.  Because of this by the time the thread wakes up the session is already expired, so I can not finish my tasks.

I am using Workstation Concurrent setting for my process.

Any suggestions on solving this problem?

In one test, I have a .NET timer set to call its callback every 2 minutes during my task.  However, I gradually see that the timer fires in 2min1sec, 2min2sec, and sometimes with over a minute of delays.

Comment: *once in a while the thread is paused because the garbage collector activates and blocks the threads.* Is your statement backed up by a profiling you did of the process or are you assuming the GC is your problem? It sounds totally unreasonable.

Comment: GC blocks threads for more than 1 minute? Never heard of it. There's no way to lower it? On dual 1.8GHZ, it takes 3.5 seconds to check 50 million objects, if all of them need to be cleaned then just 2 seconds. How many objects you allocate? Are you sure it's because of the GC?

Comment: GC should not be the reason to block you thread for one whole minute.. that is un-imaginable.. your problem likely is in CPU starvation in general.

Comment: What all of them said ^

Comment: By changing GC setting from Workstation Concurrent to Server setting I am able get the run time down to 20% of the original.  That's why I thought GC is the culprit.

Comment: `run time` of what? GC run? So you are measuring the time spent in GC (using profiler?) and it reliably shows you that time spent in GC is more than one minute? Please provide more information in the question, if that is the case. Another thing - How many threads do you think your process is running? anywhere close to 1000? In which case, you may have a case of thread pool thread starvation.

Comment: @daniely I have calculated that if it really took 1 min to collect objects then it means that you have 9TB of RAM. Is your program runs on your hard-disks?

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky The speed of the GC is dependent on the quality and load of the CPU, not just the amount of memory.  If there are other processing consuming a ton of CPU work, in combination with a lower quality CPU than you're testing with, that number could go way down.

Comment: @Servy I calculated whatever it was on 1.8GHZ CPU, I would really concerned if they have something worse. Maybe you miscalculated that when the GC runs nothing can consume CPU. (Because they are all paused) If other processes took so much that the GC left with let's say 18MHZ per second, that means that they have 100GB~ ram, 18MHZ of really bad CPU, good CPU means higher values. (Higher than 100GB) But that can't be, the OS allocates in the schedule 10MHZ each thread maximum. They have 180 threads at without sleep? And 100GB of RAM?

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky VM on shared server can take forever and some time to do any operation... Based on attempt to run long process inside ASP.Net (bad idea by itself) I suspect OP trying to sneak in some serious work on free/super cheap shared hosting where process gets just part of one VM time...

Comment: To answer the question in the title, you can simply attach a debugger and look at what the threads are doing. You'll see it in the method names. Just make sure you have debugging symbols for clr.dll.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to switch to server GC (which looks like a viable option from the discussion), you can use the GC notifications API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.waitforfullgcapproach.aspx

Then, you'll be able to receive a notification just prior to a full GC starting - which would cause pauses.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the garbage collector to not run during critical operations using the Latency Mode setting.

http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/03/Net-403

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384202(v=vs.110).aspx